# TeamCity Git fails after copying configuration

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a (**working**) TeamCity configuration that uses Git.

I now copied that working configuration, changed the name of it and also copied the VCS ruleset changing only the "Fetch URL" to my other repository.

That repository is on the same machine as the working configuration.

"Test connection" works.

When I try to run a build on the new configuration, I immediatley receive the following error:

```
[17:20:57]Patch is broken, can be found in file: E:\buildAgent1\temp\globalTmp\temp5372239496696609405patch_2821

[17:20:57]Failed to build patch for build #1.2.1-<default>.5 {build id=2821}, VCS root: "gitName" {instance id=48, parent internal id=22, parent id=xxxConfigName, description: "https://svn.domain.de/git/repositoryName#develop"}, due to error: Cannot build patch: java.io.IOException: Low-level patch stream is closed
```

On my local machine, I can pull from that Git Repository without any problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "clean " the build directory and rerun the target and see if it helps.

On aisde note, did you do a reset or rebase on the branch yu are trying to pull on the remote repository. This can sometimes lead to the above issue